# Not return all the tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, html-table

I want to try scraping all the tables form [this website](https://aws.pro-football-reference.com/teams/mia/2000.htm).This website contains more than `10` tables.When I use `pd.read_html()`,it returns only 3 tables but I expect that my script return all the tables.
My script:

```
import pandas as pd
url = "https://aws.pro-football-reference.com/teams/mia/2000.htm"
df = pd.read_html(url)
len(df)
```

Output:

```
3
```

Specially, I want this table:

[image]

How can I get all the tables using `pd.read_html()`?

Comment: When I view the link in my web browser, I see 3 tables: one titled `Team Stats and Rankings `, one titled `Schedule & Game Results ` and one titled `Team Conversions `. What else is there supposed to be?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel sir above link  for my case show more table like,  `Team Stats and Rankings`, `Schedule & Game Results`, `Team Conversions`, `Passing`, `Rushing & Receiving` and more.Even, that's the picture above

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib Many modern websites dynamically load content with JavaScript. It's possible that when you request the HTML, it's returning everything that has loaded so far. I am not sure exactly how `read_html()` works under the hood, but you could explore other options of getting the fully loaded HTML, and then processing that with pandas.

Comment: @gallen Sir, I am getting three tables, so why can't I get the rest.

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib Because at the time the request made by `read_html()` completes, there are only 3 tables rendered on the page. If the rendering process takes longer to load than the scraper waits to read, you will miss data. That's why I suggest not relying on a black box function to do it, but rather scrape it yourself and then process it after.

Comment: Have you looked into whether there is an API available for this data?  A lot of data is available through APIs these days.  Web scraping is less and less relevant.

Answer (score 1):

`pd.read_html` uses BeautifulSoup under the hood to scrape `<table>` elements from the webpage. Using `requests` to grab HTML for the webpage and parsing it manually, I found that the page you linked indeed contains only three `<table>` elements. However, the data for several additional tables (including the "kicking" one you want) can be found in HTML comments.

## Solution

Parse the commented-out tables.

```py
import requests
import bs4
import pandas as pd

url = "https://aws.pro-football-reference.com/teams/mia/2000.htm"
scraped_html = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(scraped_html.content)

# Get all html comments, then filter out everything that isn't a table
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, bs4.Comment))
commented_out_tables = [bs4.BeautifulSoup(cmt).find_all('table') for cmt in comments]
# Some of the entries in `commented_out_tables` are empty lists. Remove them.
commented_out_tables = [tab[0] for tab in commented_out_tables if len(tab) == 1]

print(len(commented_out_tables))
```

Gives `8`.

Only one of these is the "kicking" table. We can find it by looking for a `table` with the `id` attribute set to `kicking`.

```py
for table in commented_out_tables:
    if table.get('id') == 'kicking':
        kicking_table = table
        break
```

Turn this into a `pd.DataFrame` with `pd.read_html`.

```py
pd.read_html(str(kicking_table))
```

Yields the following:

```py
[  Unnamed: 0_level_0 Unnamed: 1_level_0 Unnamed: 2_level_0 Unnamed: 3_level_0 Games       ... Kickoffs Punting
                  No.             Player                Age                Pos     G   GS  ...    KOAvg     Pnt     Yds   Lng Blck   Y/P
 0                1.0          Matt Turk               32.0                  p    16  0.0  ...      NaN    92.0  3870.0  70.0  0.0  42.1
 1               10.0        Olindo Mare               27.0                  k    16  0.0  ...     60.3     NaN     NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN
 2                NaN         Team Total               27.3                NaN    16  NaN  ...     60.3    92.0  3870.0  70.0  0.0  42.1
 3                NaN          Opp Total                NaN                NaN    16  NaN  ...      NaN    87.0  3532.0   NaN  NaN  40.6

 [4 rows x 32 columns]]
```

Comment: just a fyi since oyu mentioned it, `pd.read_html()` uses beautifulsoup under the hood. It parses out the `<table>`, `<th>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags, but as you noticed, doesn't bother checking in the comments. So like you said, initially only finds 3 `<table>` elements, and then you have to pull out those others from the comments. Well done!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @chitown88! I've edited my answer to include that information as context.